# How was this edit useful?

Tags: discussion, edits

One of my questions was edited with the message "change text" and the edit got approved. However, I'm failing to see why, and how this edit is useful. Can someone please tell me if this makes the question better or something?

The edit can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19843381) and [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50544023/revisions)

Comment: It's borderline useful. I'm not sure I would have approved it. There's a lot of posts that really do need editing, yours didn't.

Comment: The first two extra line breaks are pointless. I would have rejected it.

Comment: As the author of the post, you have the ability to override the approval of the edit and reject the suggested edit. While it's already been rolled back to the version you wrote, another time, you should be able to just reject/revert the suggested edit yourself, if you feel it's not constructive.

Comment: "xxx has approved 427 edit suggestions and rejected 38 edit suggestions" is usually a certain indication that they are a robo reviewer, if not for the 109 manual edits they've done. Still this accept ratio is _way_ too high given the average quality of suggested edits.

Comment: From my previous knowledge about approvals/rejections by edits suggested by myself, it's pretty borderline. But if I have had to review it, I'd have rejected it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No, it wasn't useful in the slightest. I would've rejected that edit stating the reason as either

1. making no improvement whatesoever, or
2. being harmful, actually *hindering* readability by breaking those sentences as it has done.

If you notice this repeatedly from this user or the reviewers who approved that edit, I'd recommend flagging for moderator attention.